# A challenge with the use of filter

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I am working on a react app which is a contact manager following teaching in a course by brad traversy, and while trying to use the filter array method to delete a profile , but its not working at all, telling me cannot read the property of filter.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Contact from './Contact'

    class Contacts extends Component {
    state ={
             Contacts: [
                 {
                    id: 1,
                    name:"John Doe" ,
                    email:"olaidemmanuel0@gmail.com" ,
                    number:"08064965574"
                 }, 
                 {
                    id: 2,
                    name:"John Doe" ,
                    email:"olaidemmanuel1@gmail.com" ,
                    number:"08064965574"
                 },
                 {
                    id: 3,
                    name:"John Doe" ,
                    email:"olaidemmanuel@gmail.com" ,
                    number:"08064965574"
                 }
             ]
         };

       deleteContact = id => {
         const { contacts } = this.state;

                 //this is where i had to use the arr.filter syntax
         const newContacts = contacts.filter(contact => contact.id !== id);


           this.setState({
            contacts: newContacts
           });
        };

     render() {
        const { Contacts } = this.state;
        return (
            // <div>
                <React.Fragment>
                {Contacts.map(contact => (
                    <Contact 
                    key={contact.id}
                    contact={contact}
                    deleteClickHandler=
                    {this.deleteContact.bind(this, contact.id)}
                    /> ))}
                    </React.Fragment>
                    /* </div > */
            );

         }
      }

    export default Contacts;
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: you're sometimes referring to `this.state.contacts` with a lowercase 'c', and sometimes `Contacts` with upper case.

Comment: contacts is undefined, because you set your state with Contacts uppercase. Set it to lowercase within state ={...} and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo here for your state variable, you have state `Contacts` and trying to access `contacts` in function `deleteContact`, you need to do this,

```
deleteContact = id => {
   const { Contacts } = this.state;  

   //this is where i had to use the arr.filter syntax
   const newContacts = Contacts.filter(contact => contact.id !== id);

   this.setState({
      Contacts: newContacts
   });
};
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-n468ik)

Answer (score 2):

`Contacts` is in uppercase in your state, try to rename it to `contacts`, otherwise it is undefined, check the case